RDP won't connect through public IP even though it works over local network and port is open
I've already forwarded the port, and according to YouGetSignal the port is open and I can already connect to the RDP using the same port and my local IP. I'm on windows Home so I have to use RDP Wrap and I'm using an xfinity gateway.

Using a VPN? Which?

are you trying to connect from outside your LAN using the WAN IP, or from within your LAN?

After not touching it for a week or two, I tried to connect again, failed, and then tried to connect again (to the host system) through a vpn (on my client system) and it just worked. A little while later and I was having the same exact problem and switching my vpn server fixed it. I have no earthly idea what the problem was, why that worked, or why trying to connect without a vpn failed, but hey, problem's solved I guess.
